# JPanel not being printed in landscape mode by default when i call the print method of printable

Tags: java, swing, printing, jpanel

Here's my function to print panel, it prints in portrait mode by default and I have to change it each time to landscape, I have never done printing with java so I cant understand most of the following code

```
    public static void Print(JPanel component){
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");

    pj.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
        public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
        if (pageNum > 0){
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
            pf=pj.defaultPage();
            Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
            paper.setSize(8.5 * 72, 14 * 72);
            paper.setImageableArea(0.5 * 72, 0.0 * 72, 8 * 72, 14 * 72);
            pf.setPaper(paper);
            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

            Book book = new Book();//java.awt.print.Book
            book.append(this, pf);
            pj.setPageable(book);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX() + pf.getImageableWidth() / 2 -  component.getWidth() / 2, pf.getImageableY() + pf.getImageableHeight() / 2 - component.getHeight() / 2);
            g2.scale(pf.getImageableWidth()/component.getWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight()/component.getHeight());
            component.paint(g2);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
  });

  if (pj.printDialog() == false)
  return;

  try {
        pj.print();
  } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        // handle exception
  }
}
```

Please Help, What I am doing wrong? I have tried many different things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm not a printing expert, but this: `catch (PrinterException ex) {
        // handle exception
  }` does not look good to me. Are you by chance ignoring a key exception?

Comment: I don't know about this but my problem is solved, I tried setting all the parameters outside the print function of printable and it works fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found the solution, Don't know much how it worked this way but I set all the paper , page format and book parameters outside the Print function and appended book with a new Printable (Passsing all the PageFormat and Paper parameters) and I got the results I wanted. Here's the code it may help someone. **Printing a Jpanel on paper in Landscae Orientation by default.**

```
public static void Print(JPanel component){
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");

    pj.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
        public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
        if (pageNum > 0){
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }    
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX() + pf.getImageableWidth() / 2 - component.getWidth() / 2, pf.getImageableY() + pf.getImageableHeight() / 2 - component.getHeight() / 2);
          //g2.scale(pf.getImageableWidth()/component.getWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight()/component.getHeight());
            component.paint(g2);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }     
  });

            PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
            pf = pj.defaultPage();
            Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
            paper.setSize(8.5 * 72, 14 * 72);
            paper.setImageableArea(0.5 * 72, 0.0 * 72, 8 * 72, 14 * 72);
            pf.setPaper(paper);
            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
            Book book = new Book();//java.awt.print.Book
            book.append((new Printable() {    
            public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
            if (pageNum > 0){
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }    
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX() + pf.getImageableWidth() / 2 - component.getWidth() / 2, pf.getImageableY() + pf.getImageableHeight() / 2 - component.getHeight() / 2);
          //g2.scale(pf.getImageableWidth()/component.getWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight()/component.getHeight());
            component.paint(g2);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }     
  }), pf);
            pj.setPageable(book); 
            if (pj.printDialog() == false)
            return;

  try {
        pj.print();
  } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        // handle exception
  }
}
```